# How to delete UILocalNotification applicationIconBadgeNumber when app is deleted from iPad?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, uilocalnotification

Whenever I delete the app from iPad in ios4, a weird thing happens:

Listed below the steps I followed:

1. Launch the app in ios4
2. Schedule the UILocalnotification, by setting applicationIconBadgeNumber
3. Quit the app by tapping on Home button
4. Delete the app from iPad
5. Relaunch the app, you can see previous local notification value in the applicationIconBadgeNumber in the app logo.

Thank you in advance, your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is know way to remove the *applicationIconBadgeNumber* when the app is deleted. It persists even after the app is deleted and installed again. I don't know if this is a bug or something. But the proper and safe way is to reset the *applicationIconBadgeNumber* whenever the app is launched.